# Arrowkey navigating through a list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make my website scroll by the use of arrowkeys. Since it's a website where each page is covering a 100% width and height, i've arranged it in li's. Note that there are li's inside the page contents as well, so I've tried to limit myself to only navigating through li's which are a child of body.

I can get my script to work using hard-coded id-tags for the li's, but since one of my pages is going to be a blog, this is not really an option where I can eliminate having to do a bit of html everytime i update this.

Can anyone figure out whats wrong with my script? Below is what I have so far + a jsfiddle recreating my problem.

```
var count = $("body li").length;
var position = 0;
var moveToElement = function() {

var elementTop = $(count[position]).offset().top;

$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").delay( 0 ).animate({ scrollTop: elementTop-20}, 400 );
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 38:
                // Go up
                if(position > 0)
                    position--;
                break;
            case 40:
                // Go down
                if(position < count.length - 1)
                    position++;
                break;
            default:

                return;
        }

        moveToElement();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jNc68/2/

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what you wanted it to do (scroll between items on each keypress). It was a trivial bug as you called it `count`, but actually used it as a JQuery collection of elents. Suggest you call it `$elements` or something more meaningful.

Comment: +1 for providing a JSFiddle. You need to be clearer about your aims though, as the expected operation was not obvious from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/jNc68/5/

You were getting the length of the collection instead of the list of items. Should have been:

```
var count = $("body li");
```

not

```
var count = $("body li").length;
```

as you were indexing into it with `$(count[position])`

As "count" is already a JQuery collection, you can use this instead to index it:

```
var elementTop = count.eq(position).offset().top;
```

As `count` was a misleading variable name for a JQuery object, suggest you change it to something like `$elements` (a `$` prefix is one naming standard for JQuery objects):

### http://jsfiddle.net/jNc68/6/

*Please note: it is not valid HTML to have `LI`s outside of a `UL` or `UL` element. It is only because browsers are very fault tolerant that it works.

Comment: This works like a charm. Come to think about it I don't know what I was thinking adding the .lenght; to the count variable.

And you're so right about the LI-point. I guess that also protects me from counting li-child-li's into my $elements, because I can just use var $elements = $("ol li");

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Do you reckon there's any way to make it detect what LI you're at, before taking action? As it is currently, if I start at 1, scroll past 2 & 3 and then press my down-key, it should take me to 4, but it takes me back to 2?

Comment: You can calculate the current position of each item and compare to scrolltop. From that you could calculate if you want that index +1 or -1. You could forgot the index method completely then (and just scroll to the next/prev element).

Comment: @heyimblomblom: if you want to ask that as another question I have a working answer ready

Comment: Will do! Been fiddling around with it for some time now but I can't seem to get my head around converting offset into my li position.

Comment: Basically throw away the position (you don't need it for relative operations) :) I have posted the other answer for you.